# Obter página com PHP ou Ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, seo

Eu possuo o seguinte `código` para obter páginas no meu **conteúdo** com `url` *amigável*:

```
<?php
$url = (isset($_GET['url'])) ? $_GET['url'] : 'home';

$url = array_filter(explode('/', $url));

$file = './pages/' . $url[0] . '.php';

if (is_file($file)) {
  include_once $file;
} else {
  include_once './pages/404.php';
}
?>
```

Mas aí surgiu a dúvida, "?", Qual melhor método de fazer isto, com `php` ou `ajax` ? Qual é mais seguro, Qual interfere mais no `SEO` do WebSite? Qual é mais ágil?

Comment: Qual motivo da sinalização? Minha pergunta está bem clara, favor deixar um *comentário*

Comment: O segundo voto de fechamento é meu. Para entender, o que apresentou é confuso, não claro o suficiente e mesmo que fosse claro parece ser amplo demais que é a escolha do primeiro que votou.
Mas vou te dar uma chance. Talvez esclarecendo melhor o que pretende e qual a finalidade disso aí. A confusão está em "ajax" pois ajax parece não ter nenhuma utilidade aí no que apresentou. A menos que explique o contexto e, como falta isso, foi o que me motivou a votar como **não clara o suficiente**. Achou o comentário confuso? Imagine para quem lê o que postou.. rsr

Comment: Verdade é que eu não tenho o código ajax ainda, mas a pergunta a baixo é que está valendo... não o código apresentado pra deixar claro.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Acho que entendi sua pergunta. Bom vamos lá.

**1º**- AJAX não pode ser comparado com PHP, pois, é um plugin do Jquery para fazer coisas como requisições sem da refresh na página ou ate mesmo recebe textos como JSON ou fazer uma validação de senha, tudo isso levando em conta que você esta usando o php como back-end.

**2º**- PHP é a melhor maneira de fazer oque você quer. Pois você esta fazendo includes de arquivos na sua página e provavelmente esses includes contem valores e variáveis que precisam ser usadas em algum lugar do teu código.

Comment: Tá certo, acho que não haverá resposta melhor. Em questão ao SEO, pesquisei e não encontrei nada a respeito.